# I'm getting this error when I 'git push heroku master' for my discord.js bot

Tags: node.js, git, github, heroku, npm

So I have a discord bot written in js and I wanted to host it using Heroku because you get 1000 hours of hosting per month for free. I read some guides and stuff, but no matter what I did I get this error when I push on Heroku with `git push heroku master`. (I have Procfile configured):
**error**

```
Enumerating objects: 62, done.
Counting objects: 100% (62/62), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (54/54), done.
Writing objects: 100% (62/62), 8.80 KiB | 1.76 MiB/s, done.
Total 62 (delta 18), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:        
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  10.x
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 10.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 10.19.0...
remote:        Using default npm version: 6.13.4
remote:        
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        
remote:        > node@13.8.0 preinstall /tmp/build_bb6a303ef77491603b3088575e05b576/node_modules/node
remote:        > node installArchSpecificPackage
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! code ETARGET
remote:        npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for node-linux-x64@13.8.0.
remote:        npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are requesting
remote:        npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.HDmIW/_logs/2020-02-24T17_35_08_149Z-debug.log
remote:        internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
remote:            throw err;
remote:            ^
remote:        
remote:        Error: Cannot find module 'node-linux-x64/package.json'
remote:            at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
remote:            at Function.resolve (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:33:19)
remote:            at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_bb6a303ef77491603b3088575e05b576/node_modules/node-bin-setup/index.js:18:27)
remote:            at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
remote:            at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
remote:            at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
remote:        npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote:        npm ERR! errno 1
remote:        npm ERR! node@13.8.0 preinstall: `node installArchSpecificPackage`
remote:        npm ERR! Exit status 1
remote:        npm ERR! 
remote:        npm ERR! Failed at the node@13.8.0 preinstall script.
remote:        npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
remote:        
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.HDmIW/_logs/2020-02-24T17_35_08_183Z-debug.log
remote: 
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:        
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:        
remote:        Some possible problems:
remote:        
remote:        - A module may be missing from 'dependencies' in package.json
remote:          https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys#ensure-you-aren-t-relying-on-untracked-dependencies
remote:        
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:        
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to b-r-u-h-discord-bot.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/b-r-u-h-discord-bot.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/b-r-u-h-discord-bot.git'
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "bruh-bot",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "description": "This is B R U H bot ",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "test": "!test",
        "start": "node index.js"
    },
    "author": "da_dev",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "@discordjs/uws": "^10.149.0",
        "discord.js": "^11.5.1"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "10.x"
    },
    "devDependencies": {},
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "git+https://github.com/da-the-dev/b-r-u-h.git"
    },
    "bugs": {
        "url": "https://github.com/da-the-dev/b-r-u-h/issues"
    },
    "homepage": "https://github.com/da-the-dev/b-r-u-h#readme"
}
```

I spent an entire day surfing the web with no success. 
 Maybe someone has an idea of how to deal with this issue?

Comment: You are installing node. And with node you are installing your dependencies. You then depend on node in your dependencies. `node-linux-x64`

Comment: @TinNguyen, so I just need to `npm install node-linux-x64`?

Comment: @TinNguyen, I read through the error and I think that version of my node doesn't match the node version in the error. I tried to specify the version in `package.json` in `engines.node`, but it doesn't change anything.

Comment: You are not supposed to install node again. You already installed node. With node you are installing other dependencies. But in your package.json you are installing node with node. Furthermore you are on node 10.19.0 and you are trying to install node 13.8.0.

Comment: @TinNguyen, I am sorry for my stupidity, but I still didn't get it. I added `package.json`, maybe that will help. What should I remove/add in it?

Comment: `npm uninstall node --save` this will remove `"node": "^13.8.0"` from your `package.json`.
It is trying to install node version 13.8.0 while Heroku is already using node version 10.19.0

Comment: @TinNguyen, it still doesn't wanna push :(. The same error pops up, it says that I'm missing a module from 'dependencies' in 'package.json' (which I've just updated). Any other way of making this work?